# YoutubePlayerFragment doesn't load age restrict content

Tags: android, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to load a video using YoutubePlayerFragment but when I load it, a request to sign in to confirm my age appears.

Even if I authenticate with Google Play Services and get a token, how can I use it with Youtube Data API 3.0 classes?

For example, to initialize a YoutubePlayerFragment you only have to do something like this:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
                (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(KEY, this);
```

How can I pass this token that I got using Google Play Services to YoutubePlayerFragment?